Replace default props in react-admin
I'm having components like this and they work:
import { formatFileNumber } from "@components";
import type { ClientCompliance } from "@types";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import type { FieldProps } from "react-admin";
import { sanitizeFieldRestProps, useRecordContext } from "react-admin";

interface FileNumberFieldProps extends Omit<FieldProps, "source"> {}

const FileNumberField = (props: FileNumberFieldProps) => {
  const record = useRecordContext<ClientCompliance>();
  const { ...rest } = props;

  if (!record) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <Typography
      component="span"
      variant="body2"
      {...sanitizeFieldRestProps(rest)}
    >
      {record.fileNumber ? formatFileNumber(record.fileNumber) : ""}
    </Typography>
  );
};

FileNumberField.displayName = "FileNumberField";
FileNumberField.defaultProps = { sortable: true, sortBy: "fileNumber" };

export default FileNumberField;

However, I see that default props are deprecated and there's a warning:

Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.

How can I replace the default props in such a component when I don't can destructure the props inside the function arguments?

Actually sortable and sortBy are props read by <Datagrid>, which is one of the few components to still clone its children in react-admin v5.
So setting default values for the props at the component level probably won't be enough, you also need to declare them explicitly in your <Datagrid> (even though <FileNumberField> doesn't actually use those props):
<Datagrid>
  <FileNumberField sortable sortBy="fileNumber">
</Datagrid>

React deprecated defaultProps but they did not really provide a replacement solution for this use-case as far as I'm aware :(.

React is probably doing something like this internally to make it work.
Object.assign({}, defaultProps, props)

This way they merge your default props with the props before passing them into the component.
You can do the same thing inside the component if you want to keep your props in one place
const newProps = Object.assign({ sortable: true, sortBy: "fileNumber" }, props)
// or
const newProps = { sortable: true, sortBy: "fileNumber", ...props };

If you don't need to keep the props all in one place, you can use function default parameters as it suggests you
const FileNumberField = ({sortable = true, sortBy = "fileNumber", ...rest}) => ...

Now sortable and sortBy does not exist in rest
And here you have to combine them again
  {...sanitizeFieldRestProps({sortable, sortBy, ...rest})}

